# E2E testing: Karma+JQuery vs Protractor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, protractor, karma-runner, e2e-testing

**Question**

In terms of e2e testing, what can't we do with `Karma` and `JQuery` that is possible with `Protractor`?

**Explanation**

I'm currently building a testing framework for my JavaScript application.
I'm using `Karma` for *Unit Testing* and `Protractor` for *E2E Testing* as suggested by many people.

I'm aware of the conceptual differences between unit testing and e2e testing, but, in the context of JavaScript, I don't clearly understand why we need framework like `Protractor`.

As far as I know, the point of e2e testing is to use the application as a *simple* end-user. For that, tools like Protractor use a `webdriver` to interact with a browser and let us simulate some *user events* (clicking on element, filling forms...).

The thing is, why can't we simply do this by using `Karma` and `JQuery`?

Indeed, `JQuery` comes with lots of methods to interact with a DOM element (trigger event, get/set element's property, set value to an input...). Furthermore, it provides *selectors* which make the selection of DOM element very easy.

From my point of view, `Karma` and `JQuery` has (almost) everything needed for e2e testing (if we don't take care of the browser's window's operations available in `Protractor` which enable for example to set the window size or location).

I'm obviously missing something, any clarification will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery and Karma the way you would, is a behavior-driven-test but not an end-to-end test.

With Jquery and Karma, you can't detect cross-browser issues like you would in protractor. Protractor on the other hand runs your tests as if it was an end-user. It literally opens the browser you want and tests your application in that browser.